# Orchard CMS Send Email to Multiple/Different Email Addresses Upon Form Submission Using Workflows

Tags: forms, email, workflow, orchardcms, contacts

I built a custom (contact us) form that contains a dropdown list with several options I need to create a workflow that sends an email to a specific address based on which item in the dropdown list was selected, but I've no idea how to go about doing this as the workflows in orchard only allow for sending an email when the form is submitted and not based on any of the content that was in the form. Is this possible? Will I need to create a custom workflow activity that somehow searches the contents of the form for user specified text and then send an email if the text is found in the form?

Comment: In sending emails with workflows you can use tokens for retrieving data of the filled in form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to code a new workflow activity. Only way to avoid it, is to send emails to a gateway address that has conditional filters which you can use for routing logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can write a little C# code, you can use the Decision activity provided by the C# Scripting module.

Running this activity before the one that sends the email, you can do something like this:

```
var office = "{Content.Fields.ContactUs.Office}";
var email = "";

if (office == "LONDON") email = "london@[...].com";
else if (office == "PARIS") email = "jacques@[...].com";
else if (office == "GLOBAL") email = "world@[...].com;

Workflow.SetState("EmailAddress", email);
SetOutcome("Done");
```

There would be only one Possible Outcome for the Decision activity: "Done". On the Send Email activity, you would get the email address like this:

```
{Workflow.State:EmailAddress}
```

Note: if using Orchard 1.8, and the "Workflow.SetState()" method, please see this: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/568460